# jQuery UI Autocomplete in ASP.NET MVC 4 does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm deploying autocomplete jQueryUI in ASP.NET MVC 4 but it wasn't working perfectly. When I typed a name of Bike, it displays an error like this **parsererror**. Here's my simply code:

```
public JsonResult GetAutoComplete(string modelname)
    {
        var result = db.Products;
        var search = result.Where(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(modelname.ToLower())).ToList();
        return this.Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Javascript function to provide AutoComplete and Intellisense feature for finding Users.
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Name").autocomplete({
        source: '@Url.Action("", "StoreManager")'
    });
});
 </script>
<p>
    Search the Name of Bikes @Html.TextBox("Name")
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="GetName" />
</p>
```

Does anyone can tell me where I'm doing something wrong ? I just updated my code.

Comment: set source:'source: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")' remove all ajax methods and try again

Comment: It's not working @unique

Comment: Seems like your action incorrect because you need to show suggestions below the text box. then you need to provide all values to  action so rename GetAutoComplete Action to Return type ActionResult and return all products as a this.Json(db.Products, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); it is works for me If you need to verify keep debug point on your GetAutoComplete action and check whether it come to your action when you type some charactors of the text box - Hope this will helps.

Comment: I just fixed my code, could you please take a look at it? I'm following the way that you mentioned, when I typed in **Textbox**, it returned a message **No search result**.

Comment: Where are you sending value to `modelName`?

Comment: Value **Name** is the name of bike

Comment: @TrungPham you should return search variable not result variable sorry I forget to tell that

Comment: It still got a message **No search result**, even I typed exactly a name of Bike.

Comment: And I returned **search** variable but it still didn't work.

Comment: It worked, when I replaced string **modelname** to **term**. Thanks for all replying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this it may helpful to you.

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
      $('#Name').autocomplete({
          source: '@Url.Action("GetAutoComplete")',
          minLength: 3,
          select: function (evt, ui) {
            }
      });
  });
 </script>
```